# Dynamic ng-model of input can't access in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `data` array and i want to create `$scope` variables dynamically in my controller and assign the values of array. after that in my view i want to access these variables in `ng-model` there name should create dynamically as in controller. but i cant get these values. if i write these `ng-model` name statically its working but when i try to concatenate the name its not working.
if anybody can help me. thanks a lot in advance.

## **In controller**

```
$scope.data = [ {id:2, Name:'jon'}, {id:3, Name:'XXXXX'}, {id:4,Name:'NNNN'} ];  
for(var V in $scope.data){  
   $scope['value'+V. id] = V.Name;  
}

$scope.update = function(){
  for(var V in $scope.data){  
     console.log($scope['value'+V. id]);  
  }
}
```

## **In View**

```
<ul>  
   <li ng-repeat='V in data'>  
      <input type="text" ng-model="value[V.id]"/>
   </li>
<ul>
<button ng-click="update()">update</button>
```

Comment: Do you want to update name of person ??

Comment: it's really a weird kind of binding I've ever seen!!!

Comment: yes @Kaustubh Khare. i never want to get value from input field with extra code after edit. i want to get just these `$scope` variables and send it to database for update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. Then you can take updated object and send to database.

**Controller :**

```
$scope.data = [ {id:2, Name:'jon'}, {id:3, Name:'XXXXX'}, {id:4,Name:'NNNN'} ];
```

**HTML :**

```
<ul>  
   <li ng-repeat='V in data'>  
      <input type="text" ng-model="V.Name"/> {{V.Name}}
   </li>
<ul>
<button ng-click="update()">update</button>
```

Comment: dear @Kaustubh Khare i know with this code i can get value from data object to input field but after that in controller in can not access `$scope` variable of `ng-model`.

Comment: @sajid same way you can get updated value in `data` variable after you changed from input field. After click you will get updated data.